# Invalid Identifier F.INDEX in SNOWFLAKE on joining dimension table column with array of value

Tags: arrays, join, indexing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was trying to join a dimension table column (PRODUCTID) to an array of value that comes from staging table but I am getting the error **Invalid Identifier F.INDEX**

Could someone please help me with this join statement.

Below is the code

```
merge into PRODUCTDETAILS as a using (
                        select 
                        c.PRODUCTID,
                        f.value as PRODUCTunit,
                        PRODUCTDisplayname[f.index]::Varchar as PRODUCTDisplayname,
                        PRODUCTCODE [f.index]::Varchar as PRODUCTCODE,
                        PRODUCTquantity [f.index]::Varchar as PRODUCTquantity,
                        PRODUCTDate [f.index]::Timestamp as PRODUCTDate
                        from json js join DIM_PRODUCTS c on js.PRODUCTDisplayname[f.index] = c.PRODUCTNAME,
                        LATERAL FLATTEN(PRODUCTunit, RECURSIVE=>true)f) as b on a.PRODUCTDate = b.PRODUCTDate
                                                                                 and a.PRODUCTCODE = b.PRODUCTCODE and a.PRODUCTID = b.PRODUCTID
                                                                                 and a.PRODUCTquantity = b.PRODUCTquantity
                        when not matched then insert (CUSTOMERID, PRODUCTID, PRODUCTunit, PRODUCTDisplayname, PRODUCTCODE, PRODUCTquantity, PRODUCTDate) 
                        values (CUSTOMERID, PRODUCTID, PRODUCTunit, PRODUCTDisplayname, PRODUCTCODE, PRODUCTquantity, PRODUCTDate)
```

Comment: `from json js 
 join DIM_PRODUCTS c on js.PRODUCTDisplayname[f.index] = c.PRODUCTNAME` Joins are resolved left to right, top-down. f.index does not exist on that context

Answer (score 0):

In your code the LATERAL FLATTEN() step is happening *after* the JOIN to DIM_PRODUCTS, so at the time of the join the "f" alias for the output of the flatten step does not yet exist.

To correct this perform the FLATTEN step first (e.g. in a CTE or subquery) and then join the result to DIM_PRODUCTS.

Comment: Hi @Nathan Griffiths,
Thanks for the reply, could you please provide me a sample CTE with my above merge  statement  if you don't mind, I tried them and still not working.